# Show contact form in block only, not page?

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I'm using the Contact and Contact Form Blocks modules to create a contact form and display it in a block.

The problem is that the Contact module creates a page but I don't want a page, only the block.

Is this possible, perhaps with a different set of modules? If not then I guess I can deny access to the page using .htaccess, but that seems a bit of a hack (although since it's easier to do that than to add custom code, I'm not really interested in a custom code solution).

EDIT: I've tried using a webform instead but have the same issue. There's an option to make the webform available in a block, but the page (node) is also created

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this? I also want to put the contact form on a another page, not on its own page. You didn't select one of the answers offered, so I wonder what solution you found to this.

Comment: I ended up using Webform, creating a block as well as a node. I don't remember what (if anything) I ended up doing to stop people mistakenly navigating to the node page. I may have just added it to robots.txt so it wouldn't be indexed by search engines. In any case the offered answers did not help me get rid of the node page so I didn't accept them

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) for contact forms. It comes with the option to make it available as a block. Here's a quick screenshot of the option:

[image: Webform available as block]

You can also add other function like email notification, AJAX, template for confirmation page, etc. It's a highly customizable module, very recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The [Views Contact Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contact_form)  module might help you or else you can create a custom contact us for and display it in the [`hook_block`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7/search/hook_block).